# Ruby on Rails Saving to Database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi i'm a beginner in Ruby on Rails
Here is my doubt.
I have this method in my controller

```
def save_profile
    p "======================================"
    p params
    p "======================================"
    p params[:company][:job_locations_attributes]
    p "company_params------------------------"
    p company_params
    p "--------------------------------------"
    company_profile
    @location = JobLocation.new(:city_id => params[:city_id])
    @location.save
    if @company.update_attributes(company_params)
      redirect_to company_dashboard_path(@company.id)
    else
      render 'company_profile'
    end
  end
```

and in terminal i get the output like

```
"======================================"
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kbId4JgeaM+mGlmZC1U4gFCUYN7LHmuqWq8Es3rxa+k=", "company"=>{"name"=>"Besole", "address"=>"<p>Besole, Besole, Besole, Besole</p>", "employee_count"=>"> 200", "company_type"=>"Business", "foundation_year"=>"2020", "mission"=>"Besolification", "website"=>"https://www.besole.com", "facebook_page_url"=>"https://www.facebook.com/besole", "twitter_page_url"=>"https://www.twitter.com/besole", "description"=>"Besole besole Besole Besole Besole Besole besole", "delete_logo"=>"", "logo_crop_x"=>"", "logo_crop_y"=>"", "logo_crop_h"=>"", "logo_crop_w"=>"", "jobs_attributes"=>{"33"=>{"id"=>"33", "company_id"=>"11", "title"=>"Besoler", "description"=>"<p>besoler besoler besoler</p>", "job_type_id"=>"1", "experience"=>"1 - 3 Years", "job_category_id"=>"2", "skill_ids"=>["", "6", "5", "7", "9", "11", "12", "16", "15"], "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "job_locations_attributes"=>{"33"=>{"job_locations"=>"2"}}}, "city_id"=>"40035", "portfolios_id"=>"321", "commit"=>"Submit", "controller"=>"companies", "action"=>"save_profile", "id"=>"11"}
"======================================"
{"33"=>{"job_locations"=>"2"}}
"company_params------------------------"
{"name"=>"Besole", "logo_crop_h"=>"", "logo_crop_w"=>"", "logo_crop_x"=>"", "logo_crop_y"=>"", "delete_logo"=>"", "address"=>"<p>Besole, Besole, Besole, Besole</p>", "employee_count"=>"> 200", "company_type"=>"Business", "mission"=>"Besolification", "website"=>"https://www.besole.com", "description"=>"Besole besole Besole Besole Besole Besole besole", "foundation_year"=>"2020", "facebook_page_url"=>"https://www.facebook.com/besole", "twitter_page_url"=>"https://www.twitter.com/besole", "jobs_attributes"=>{"33"=>{"id"=>"33", "company_id"=>"11", "title"=>"Besoler", "description"=>"<p>besoler besoler besoler</p>", "job_type_id"=>"1", "experience"=>"1 - 3 Years", "job_category_id"=>"2", "skill_ids"=>["", "6", "5", "7", "9", "11", "12", "16", "15"], "_destroy"=>"false"}}}
"--------------------------------------"
```

I want to get that 33 and Job Locations..
I want to save those two variables inside table Location under columns job_id and state_id where job_id is 33 and state_id is 2

Comment: not able to understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to keep it short

```
job_id, state_id = params[:company][:job_locations_attributes].first

Location.create(:job_id => job_id, state_id => state_id.values[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use it.

```
job_id = params[:company][:job_locations_attributes].keys[0] 

state_id = params[:company][:job_locations_attributes][job_id]['job_locations']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the hash values like this,

```
params[:company][:job_locations_attributes].keys.first => "33" 
params[:company][:job_locations_attributes].values.first["job_locations"] => "2"
```

you can use the values to create location like this,

```
Location.create(:job_id => params[:company][:job_locations_attributes].keys.first, :state_id => params[:company][:job_locations_attributes].values.first["job_locations"])
```

Would recommend to send job_id and state_id in seperate params from your view with names like *job_id* and *state_id*, so that we can get the job_id and state_id as `params[:job_id]` and `params[:state_id]`